# How can I get distance using geoSearch in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am succeed in using geoNear() to get all shops with distance;

I am successed in using geoSearch() to get the shops in a special type without showing me distance.

How can I list the shops in a special type as well as showing me the distance?

```
Model.geoNear({
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": opts.coordinates
}, {
lean: true,
spherical: true,
includeLocs: true,
maxDistance: opts.radius / EARTH_RADIUS,
distanceMultiplier: EARTH_RADIUS
}, function(err, shops, stats) {
var results = exports.trimedDistance(shops);
deferred.resolve(results);
});
```

--

```
 Model.geoSearch({
_category: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(opts.categoryId)
}, {
near: opts.coordinates,
lean: true,
limit: 10,
maxDistance: opts.radius / EARTH_RADIUS
}, function(err, shops) {
var results = exports.trimedDistance(shops);
deferred.resolve(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Using geoNear Aggregate
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/